# ssh connection made using pxssh breaks when npm install is run. Why?

Tags: python, node.js, bash, npm, ssh

I am writing a python script for deploying my node project on an ec2 instance. Every thing runs just fine except when the script reaches `npm run server`.
The command runs and things start getting installing then the script suddenly breaks and no errors are shown.

I've tried putting exception handling on it to catch the error but no.
It seems it is timeout related problem maybe but I cannot pin it down to that.  Any ideas how to tackle the timeout error here in pxssh would be very helpful.

```
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    s.login(hostname, username, password,
            sync_multiplier=3, auto_prompt_reset=False)
    s.sendline('killall -s KILL node')
    s.sendline('mkdir app')
    s.sendline('unzip app.zip -d app') 
    s.sendline('cd app')
    try:
        s.sendline('npm i')
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
    s.sendline('clear')
    s.sendline('npm run server')
    s.prompt()
    print s.before
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
    print "pxssh failed on login."
    print str(e)
```

This is what i see right now.

```
:~/webapp$ npm i
clear
npm run server
[           .......] / extract:lcid: sill extract lcid@2.0.0 extracted to /home
MacBook-Pro:Downloads dev$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create a simple npm app that installs only one package? So you could see if it's about a timeout problem.  By the way, you can increase pxssh's timeout by `s = pxssh.pxssh(timeout=number)`

Comment: I actually did `s = pxssh.pxssh(timeout=500)` but now it seems nothing is happening it's just waiting till the timeout, so maybe it wasn't timeout error.

Comment: Can you try to write `npm install > "/dev/null" 2>&1` instead of `npm i`, so it runs silentish?